# Searchable Lightning Combobox LWC

Tags: search, lightning-combobox

Hello guys I have a lightning combobox that has like 600 values. I would like to be able to search the values instead of scrolling.

My .js code is this one:

```
picklistOrdered = [];
    connectedCallback(){
        getValuesFromTable().then((result) => {
            this.picklistOrdered = result.map(({value: label, key: value}) => ({ label,value}))
            this.picklistOrdered = this.picklistOrdered.sort((a,b)=>{
                if(a.label < b.label){
                    return -1
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Could someone help me and put an example? Thanks

Comment: you can press buttons on keyboard after clicking at the combobox, it will jump to the values based on the letter key you press.

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky yeah but that is not what I want I want to be able to put an input and search by that

Comment: got it, I have a suggestion. will put in an answer

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky thanks

Comment: The input has to be in the combobox

Comment: You will have to go with a custom component, I needed one some time ago, and I think this is the one I have used in the end https://github.com/benedwards44/lwc-combobox-autocomplete

Comment: @TechGuy I think Damecek's answer fits your need

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky could you share your approach? Damecek is giving me problems

Comment: @Damecek your code is giving me some problems. In your principal component you declare the some values and labels. But in my case I am getting the value from an other js file. But the problem is telling me that this.options in connectedCallback can not be iterable

Comment: @TechGuy added my implementation as a separated answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simpler implementation of the "searchable combobox" as Damecek proposed in the comments under the question.

I used the standard [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example) component of type "search" and the [blueprint of the combobox options from SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/?variant=deprecated-multi-entity#site-main-content) to imitate its usual appearance. It has the basic functionality of displaying all options on input focus, as the default combobox does, and filters picklist options based on user's input.

The only problem, options are not being hidden on blur.

**html**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <lightning-input label="Searchable Combobox" type="search" onfocus={showPicklistOptions}
                    onchange={search} value={selectedValue}>
                </lightning-input>
                <div if:true={searchResults} class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid"
                    role="listbox">
                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                        <template for:each={searchResults} for:item="searchResult">
                            <li key={searchResult.value} data-value={searchResult.value} role="presentation"
                                onclick={selectSearchResult} class="slds-listbox__item">
                                <div class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small "
                                    role="option">
                                    <span class="slds-media__body">
                                        <span class="slds-truncate" title={searchResult.label}>
                                            {searchResult.label}
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**js**

```
export default class SearchableCombobox extends LightningElement {
  picklistOrdered;
  searchResults;
  selectedSearchResult;

  get selectedValue() {
    return this.selectedSearchResult ? this.selectedSearchResult.label : null;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    getValuesFromTable().then((result) => {
        this.picklistOrdered = result.map(({value: label, key: value}) => ({ label,value}))
        this.picklistOrdered = this.picklistOrdered.sort((a,b)=>{
            if(a.label < b.label){
                return -1
            }
        })
    })
  }

  search(event) {
    const input = event.detail.value.toLowerCase();
    const result = this.picklistOrdered.filter((picklistOption) =>
      picklistOption.label.toLowerCase().includes(input)
    );
    this.searchResults = result;
  }

  selectSearchResult(event) {
    const selectedValue = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
    this.selectedSearchResult = this.picklistOrdered.find(
      (picklistOption) => picklistOption.value === selectedValue
    );
    this.clearSearchResults();
  }

  clearSearchResults() {
    this.searchResults = null;
  }

  showPicklistOptions() {
    if (!this.searchResults) {
      this.searchResults = this.picklistOrdered;
    }
  }
}
```

**demo**
[image: demo]

Comment: can you share the options? and how did you put them in the html?

Comment: connectedCallback logic is the same as yours, I just have a list of accounts in my case. take a look at the showPicklistOptions method from my answer. it just shows a list of picklist options from connectedCallback if search is not being performed

Comment: for the on blur, I think I had div with backdrop slds class and on click event which hide the list

Comment: for the on blur, just call `clearSearchResults`

Comment: @Abbas the problem with it, onblur will be triggered when you click on the option you want to select

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky true. Facing the same challenge. Now wondering how did the backdrop solution worked for - damecek

Comment: @Anton Kutishevsky could you please paste whole code for searchable combobox along with getValuesfromTable method

Comment: Hi @ArundhatiBhure, it's the whole code. Since the OP didn't post his implementation of the getValuesfromTable method, I just created an apex method that takes the first 10 accounts and returns their names mapped by ids; nothing special here.

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky This may not be the best solution, but in my onblur method I added a timeout (like 200ms) that would hide the options. That way there was enough time to save the selected option to a variable, and then 200ms later the popup would close. Again, definitely not the best option, but worked for my use case.

Comment: @TylerEdwards Thank you. Yes, it can serve as a workaround, but I would not rely on it.

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky if the lightning-input is required, an error message is shown if the user selects an option. This is because the validation of lightning-input is called when the user starts typing and then selects an option. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @AndreasEpping I think this is the same issue as with onblur event. In your case you can prevent the default validation and validate the field when you are performing an action based on the field value.